# Generic assignment in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this method:

```
class BottomPickerPanelView<T: Equatable>: UIView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

private var data: [String: T]? = nil

public static func create<T: Equatable>(controller: UIViewController, values: [String: T]?) -> BottomPickerPanelView {

                let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BottomPickerPanelView", owner: controller, options: nil)!.first as! BottomPickerPanelView

                view.isHidden = true

                view.pickerView.delegate = view
                view.pickerView.dataSource = view

                view.parentViewController = controller
                view.data = values

                return view
            }
    }
```

where 'view.data' is of type [String: T]? and T is, of course, a generic type. As you can see 'values' and 'data' are of the same type, but I get the following error: `Cannot assign value of type '[String : T]?' to type '[String : _]?'`.

Comment: `data` can't be `[String: T]?`. `BottomPickerPanelView` is not generic.

Comment: Show the declaration of `data`.

Comment: private var data: [String: T]? = nil and BottomPickerPanelView is declared as: BottomPickerPanelView<T: Equatable>, so it is generic. I've modified the code fragment to include the missing declarations

Comment: Try `as! BottomPickerPanelView<T>`.

Comment: The problem with your code is that the compiler cannot figure out what the `T` in `BottomPickerPanelView<T>` is, just by looking at the `let view = ...` line. By adding `<T>`, you tell the compiler this information.

Comment: Dear @Sweeper I'm really stupid.... I didn't see the declaration of 'view'....

Answer (score 1):

When you use `BottomPickerPanelView` without `<T>`, the compiler can't know what the generic type is. Add `<T>` to the return type and the cast and the assignment works:

```
class BottomPickerPanelView<T: Equatable>: UIView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    private var data: [String: T]? = nil

    public static func create<T: Equatable>(controller: UIViewController, values: [String: T]?) 
        -> BottomPickerPanelView<T> {
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BottomPickerPanelView", owner: controller, options: nil)!.first 
            as! BottomPickerPanelView<T>

        view.isHidden = true

        view.pickerView.delegate = view
        view.pickerView.dataSource = view

        view.parentViewController = controller
        view.data = values

        return view
    }
}
```